# What scheduling algorithm is used in android?

Tags: android, algorithm, scheduling

Android is very popular OS and I Wanted to develop something on OS level in android. I have Xperia M which is a dual core. I have a watch on the system programming and noticed that the other core remains idle most of the time. So I just wanted to know which scheduling algorithm is used in android.

Comment: Android is not a single system, and as such, different manufactures can configure the Kernel to use different scheduling algorithms.

Comment: This question is not related to programming and seems off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your help David. I got some info here http://www.quora.com/What-process-scheduling-algorithms-does-Android-use

Answer (score 0):

android is based on Linux 2.6.23 kernel and uses Completely fair scheduling (CFS)